# I would like to calculate shipping rates relative to the weight or litres of a product

Tags: product, checkout

I ve created several products which have a dropdown field included in which the customer can choose between 3 options - they vary by litres f.E 250ml, 500ml ,1l

My first problem is calculating the weight from the option that the user has made.

My second problem is calculating shipping costs by productweight.

Currently all my products have the thestweight of "1"
and my csv looks like that :

[image: table]

although when i try to upload it i get the following error : *File has not been imported. See the following list of errors: Invalid Table Rates format in the Row #2*

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Is it configurable products or is it custom options?

Comment: its custom options (the last thing when creating a new article)

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not respect custom options when calculate shipping I'm afraid.  Please consider configurable products instead.

Comment: How would i have to setup a configurable product ?

I thought that the options thing will work ,since the costs of the product are getting calculated perfectly

Comment: The issue with custom option is they can not add weight :(  Please see http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Comment: I've managed to create configureable products, and updated my csv file with weights but whenever i am in the checkout process i get the following error at shipping : 

This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.